# Android parse JavaScript function from web

Tags: javascript, android

My coworker created a website with statistics that now I need to implement on a mobile app.
He used JavaScript and now I'm developing on Android.
I want to show one specific function from the JavaScript according to the Activity on Android.
I've been searching but it is not showing anything. Any ideas? Probably I'm missing something really logical, but I can't figure out.

Code from the web:

```
function GetUsersLastEventID(userID, labelID) {
        var message = { UserID: userID };

        $.ajax({
            url: "GetData.aspx/GetUsersLastEventID",
            type: "POST",
            async: true,
            data: JSON.stringify(message),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (msg) {
                $('#label' + labelID).text("UserID: " + userID + " was last seen in event : " +  msg.d);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                $('#label' + labelID).text(eventTitle + ": INFORMATION UNAVAILABLE!");
                console.log("Error in: GetUsersLastEventID(), params: " + userID);
            }
        });
    }
```

Code from the call on Android:

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.loadUrl("javascript:GetUsersLastEventID(userID, labelID);");
```

Comment: do javascript: urls work? you can set the hash and use an onhashchange handler in the web code

Comment: Sorry, didn't really understand what you mean with set the hash and so on.

Answer (score 0):

may be you should pass userID and labelID as variable if every thing is okay with webservice call in javascript

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:getUsersLastEventID("+userID+","+labelID+")");
```

Comment: I want the list of all userID that the function retrieves, not one in particular.